# Add reactive values from click events to existing data frame and update plot

Tags: r, merge, shiny, shiny-server

I'm new to using Shiny and having some problems with adding reactive values to an existing data frame.

I would like to plot a scatter plot with a regression line using some preexisting data and update it with user clicks. I found a helpful example, but I can't figure out how to store the reactive values in a data frame in order to update the regression line.

Here is what I tried. Thank you.

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),
  actionButton("updateplot", "Update Plot:"),
  actionButton("refreshlinie", "Rlinie"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  var1 <- c(3, 10, 15, 3, 4, 7, 1, 12, 8, 18, 20, 4, 4, 5, 10)
  var2 <- c(4, 10, 12, 17, 15, 20, 14, 3, 4, 15, 12, 5, 5, 6, 2)
  df <- cbind (var1, var2)

  val <- reactiveValues(clickx = NULL, clicky = NULL, data = NULL)
  observe({
    input$plot_click
    isolate({
      val$clickx = c(val$clickx, input$plot_click$x)
      val$clicky = c(val$clicky, input$plot_click$y)
      })

   # isolate({
      # val$data = rbind(df, c(val$clickx, val$clicky))   
    #})

  }) #adding clicks to list


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(val$data[,1], val$data[,2])
    input$updateplot
    isolate({
      points(val$clickx, val$clicky)
    })
      if(input$refreshlinie)
    abline(lm(val$data[,1]~ val$data[,2]))
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x = ", val$clickx, ", y = ",val$clicky, "\n")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to initialize the reactive values with the pre-existing data. Late add to the reactive values the new points added.

Bellow I put a simplified version of your code that update the points in the `vla$data` and correctly update the `abline`.

```R
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  actionButton("updateplot", "Update Plot:"),
  actionButton("refreshlinie", "Rlinie"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  var1 <- c(3, 10, 15, 3, 4, 7, 1, 12, 8, 18, 20, 4, 4, 5, 10)
  var2 <- c(4, 10, 12, 17, 15, 20, 14, 3, 4, 15, 12, 5, 5, 6, 2)
  n <- length(var1)

  # initialize reactive values with existing data
  val <- reactiveValues( clickx = NULL, clicky = NULL, data = cbind (var1, var2))

  observe({
    input$plot_click
    isolate({
      # save new points added
      val$clickx = c(val$clickx, input$plot_click$x)
      val$clicky = c(val$clicky, input$plot_click$y)
      # add new points to data
      val$data <- rbind(val$data, cbind(input$plot_click$x, input$plot_click$y))
    })
  })


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    input$updateplot
    plot(val$data[,1], val$data[,2])
    if(input$refreshlinie)
      # I changed the order of the variables to create the model.
      abline(lm(val$data[,2]~ val$data[,1]))
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    input$plot_click
    paste0("x = ", val$clickx, ", y = ",val$clicky, "\n")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly and I finally understood the code. Unfortunately, I am not experienced enough with shiny to get this project going. I posted another question regarding this app: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832436/update-data-frame-of-click-data-with-user-input). Maybe you can help me with this last thing I cant figure out.